# Draw vertical peak lines in histogram using qplot() in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I using the diamonds dataset which comes with ggplot2 and creating histograms of price field. You could load the dataset using

```
install.packages(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
```

I am trying to analyze the peak values in the histogram which I created using this line

```
qplot(price, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", col = 'blues')
```

[image]

I want to draw a peak line in this histogram and find whats the value. I have explored couple of questions here but none is working with qplot. Could anyone suggest how can I draw lines at peak values of histogram.

Comment: i think you need to define what you mean by "peak" line. where would the line(s) be in this example?

Comment: Horizontal line? vertical line? other line? Regardless, the easy answer is going to be to to transform your data into what you want to plot, then plot rather than relying on ggplot (which is a plotting package that just happens to do some basic transformations) for your data shaping.

Comment: I just want to plot a vertical line wherever there is a peak value(corresponding to y axis). @Gregor could you give me an example, it will be very helpful.

Comment: In this plot the vertical line should come in my 2nd bar since it has the highest value.

Comment: do you want a vertical line at only the highest peak?  Or at every local maximum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The manual way: you can extract the histogram information using `ggplot_build`.  Then find the maximum y-value, and the x-location of the corresponding bar in the histogram.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)

## The plot as you have it
q <- qplot(price, data = diamonds, geom = "histogram", col = 'blues')

## Get the histogram info/the location of the highest peak
stuff <- ggplot_build(q)[[1]][[1]]

## x-location of maxium
x <- mean(unlist(stuff[which.max(stuff$ymax), c("xmin", "xmax")]))

## draw plot with line
q + geom_vline(xintercept=x, col="steelblue", lty=2, lwd=2)
```

[image]

The y-value at that location is

```
## Get the y-value
max(stuff$ymax)
# [1] 13256
```

Another option using `stat_bin`, should give the same results as above, but it's more obscure because of the hidden variables.

```
q + stat_bin(aes(xend=ifelse(..count..==max(..count..), ..x.., NA)), geom="vline",
             color="steelblue", lwd=2, lty=2)
```